# Laravel 5.5: chow to clean/drop db data (not schema!) and reset auto-increment using seeder

Tags: laravel, phpunit, auto-increment, truncate, laravel-seeding

I create PHPunit tests using laravel. For each test I need to "reset" DB but dropping all tables and set up schema is very slow (on mysql) - so I would like to not change schema but only delete DATA and reset AUTO-INCREMENT counters for each table.

How I can do it using seeder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because I was unable to easily find solution on net - so after my research I create seeder leave it here for future generations ;)

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class CleanTablesSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $rows = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');
        $tables = array_column($rows, 'Tables_in_'.env('DB_DATABASE'));

        $this->clean($tables);
    }

    private function clean($tables)
    {
        Model::unguard();
        foreach ($tables as $table) {
            DB::table($table)->delete();
            DB::statement('ALTER TABLE '.$table.' AUTO_INCREMENT = 0;');
        }
    }
}
```

## Results

I have 22 tables in my DB (average 10 column per table), and only few seeder data for 5 tables. For calling `Artisan::call(...)` inside test the timing is following :

- `17.83[s]` for `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`
- `5.56[s]` for `php artisan db:seed` (using above seder)

As we see, seeder is more than 3x faster than setup schema from scratch - which give boost to developer who write automatic tests :)